# Php code not working in ajax page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to learn using AJAX but I've completely stuck somewhere.

So I have the following code:

```
<label>View as:</label> <a href ="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con1');">Test 1</a> / <a href ="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('con2');">Test 2</a><br/>
<div id = "myDiv">asdasd</div>
```

The following `.js` script:

```
function swapContent(cv) {
$("#myDiv").html("Put animated .gif here").show();
var url = templateDir;
$.post(url.concat("/profileajax.php"), {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
})
}
```

And the following `profileajax.php` page:

```
<?php
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if($contentVar == "con1") {
    echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');
}
else {
    echo "Test";
}
?>
```

However when I'm clicking on the first link, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo() in D:\Webdesign\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\globestate\profileajax.php on line 4`.

How can I make it work? (By the way I'm using Wordpress)

Comment: You need to define that function in your PHP file. Otherwise the AJAX is working *perfectly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! What I did was include this line on top of the php page: 
`require_once("../../../wp-load.php");`

Answer (score 1):

Add a definition for the `get_bloginfo()` function to your PHP -

```
<?php
function get_bloginfo($dir) {
    // just for test we'll return the argument passed in
    return $dir;
}

$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];

if($contentVar == "con1") {
    echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');
} else {
    echo "Test";
}

?>
```

Since it seems your AJAX is working you should see "template_directory" echo'd to the page.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make the profileajax.php page recognize all the wordpress functions, not only the specific get_bloginfo function

Comment: You're not including any of the wordpress functions in this PHP file.

Comment: Well that's what I want to do but I don't know how. (Sorry! I'm a beginner)

Comment: Then you need to work your way through some of the WP tutorials.

Comment: This article is a good place to begin: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins